# Adding to manytomany field returns empty queryset

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add items in the many-to-many field. After adding it, I am getting an empty queryset. It taking me crazy.

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    order = Order.objects.create(restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(code_name=restaurant_code),
        table=Table.objects.get(code_name=request.data['table']),
        customer=request.user
        )
else:
    order = Order.objects.create(restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(code_name=restaurant_code),
                                table=Table.objects.get(code_name=request.data['table'])
                                )
    for menuitem in request.data['menuItems']:
        customList = [ItemType.objects.get(id=v) for v in list(menuitem['addOns'])]
        orderedMenuItem = OrderedMenuItem.objects.create(quantity=menuitem['quantity'],
                                                        menuitem=MenuItem.objects.get(pk=menuitem['id']),
                                                        remarks=menuitem['remarks'])
    orderedMenuItem.custom_item_types.add(*customList)
    order.ordered_menu_items.add(orderedMenuItem)
order.save()
```

Here I have ItemType as manytomany field got orderedMenuItem model. When trying to add ItemType object into OrderedMenuItem model, its giving empty query set.

My models:

OrderedMenuItem

```py
class OrderedMenuItem(models.Model):
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    custom_item_types = models.ManyToManyField(ItemType, blank=True, related_name='custom_item_types')
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

ItemType:

```py
class ItemType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: This remark is not for you issue : your code is hard to understand because of **shorcutsused in the code, ie:** **Order.objects.create(restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(code_name=restaurant_code), ...)**. Try to write less condensed code to have chance for get help.

Comment: Could you please add the models' definition code?

Comment: I have added the model

Comment: Please have a care reading in this link from the docunentation. it might help you.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Other thing is that, try not instantiate directly the models inside the create.

Comment: What does `customList` return?

Comment: @BrianD It returns a list of queryset

Comment: I see so what returns an empty queryset? Do you mean when you do `orderedMenuItem.custom_item_types.all()`?

Comment: Yes, when I am printing the values of `custom_item_types` it returns an empty queryset and also nothing is added into `custom_item_types` field

Answer (score 0):

I also got into the problem recently ( first time developing with Django), got no answer on other searches, and found the mistake on my own.

My problem is that i declare ManyToManyFields without "through" parameter.
so maybe in your case change the line from:

custom_item_types = models.ManyToManyField(ItemType, blank=True, related_name='custom_item_types')

to:

custom_item_types = models.ManyToManyField(ItemType, blank=True, related_name='custom_item_types', through='')

notes: in my case, the ManytoMany relation has extra columns i need, so i defined my own intermediary( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships ).